# jFormattedText inside a jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, jformattedtextfield

I have been trying to insert jFormatted Text inside a jTable.

However, so far, I am getting this as the output.

> javax.swing.JFormattedTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$XPFillBorder@12bd4a6,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=109,g=109,b=109],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],selectedTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=51,g=153,b=255],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]   20

The code I used was as follows:

```
    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();  
    MaskFormatter mf1;
   try {
       mf1 = new MaskFormatter("*##-##-####-*****");

    JFormattedTextField abc1 = new JFormattedTextField(mf1);



  //        String header[] = new String[]{"ACCOUNT NUMBER","Col2","AMOUNT PAYABLE"};  
  //        dm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);  
  //        jTable1.setModel(dm);


    //TableColumn abc7 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    //abc1.setValue("");
    Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();  

    data.add(abc1);  
    data.add(20);  
    data.add(false);  

    dm.addRow(data);  

     TableColumn abc2 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(abc1));
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setToolTipText("Click to change the values");
    DefaultCellEditor defaultCellEditor=new DefaultCellEditor(abc1);
    abc2.setCellEditor(defaultCellEditor);
    abc2.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    jTable1.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(10, 4));
    jTable1.repaint();

    //abc7.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(abc1));
   // jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(abc1));

   } catch (Exception ex) {
       java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Multiple_Utility_Bill.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       log.debug(ex);
   }
```

Can anyone teach me on how to input the formatted text field into the jTable please?

Answer (score 2):

No need to add the `JFormattedTextField`  in your table. Just add to your table model the values to be represented in the `JFormattedTextField`.

You should implement your own `TableCellRenderer` which should return the `JFormattedTextField` component from the method

```
Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                        int row, int column);
```

Then set the renderer to your table.